# How to set timeout for piojetd backend on AIX?

Tags: aix, printing

**Question:** If we are not using rembak for print queue backend, rather piojetd, how can we set timeout for it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
0:root@SERVER:/root # lsvirprt -q printqueuename -d 'hp@printqueuename' | grep -i time
mc      String to Send to Printer "mz" Times When Job Is     \0                
mz      Number of Times To Send String "mc" to Printer       14688             
0:root@SERVER:/root #
```

It cannot be set, better to create the print queue again, but with REMBAK backend.